# How to supress updating loaded packages window during R package installation in RStudio?

Tags: r

How to disable / suppress a popup window "Updating loaded packages" which keeps showing up during `R` package installation? I am happy to have it set to "No", but I do not know how to make it work (investigated `install.packages()` args and did my googling, but did not find out).

Background: my goal is to compare the installing time of a large (2k) collection of packages. I want to make it overnight in a loop where in each iteration: (1) I remove all but `base` priority packages, (2) I measure the time of particular package installation. I must have no popup windows (which halt the process) to do this.

`sessionInfo` when I start RStudio:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1   
>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't load any packages. Or, detach them before re-installing.

Comment: @Ista I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly: I am only using e.g. `install.packages("dplyr")`; running this triggers the popup. May I somehow run `install.packages("dplyr")` without the popup? Also, I run `rm(list = ls())` before the `install.packages("dplyr")` (which I believed detaches any possibly loaded packages?) and still see the popup.

Comment: When you first start R, what does `sessionInfo()` show. Are you loading a previously saved work space? It sounds like there is some code somewhere that is loading packages for you perhaps. (`rm` does not unload packages, you need something like `detach(..., unload=TRUE)` for that.

Comment: @MrFlick I updated my answer for session info.

Comment: Don't use RStudio. If your goal is truly benchmarking package loading, you should just use command-line R. RStudio does quite a bit of "watching" what's going on in an R session under the hood (that pop up is one indicator of this). You don't want that impacting the measurement. Also, unless you really know what you're doing w/r/t pkg loading/unloading, you should really fire up a new R process then do the pkg loading (with timings) vs use the same session, otherwise you'll likely get invalid timings.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a benchmarking harness something akin to:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create file of all installed packages

Rscript -e 'writeLines(unname(installed.packages()[,1]), "installed-pkgs.txt")'

# Iterate over the file, benchmarking package load 3x (consider bumping this up)

while read -r pkg; do

  echo -n "Benchmarking package [${pkg}]"

  for iter in {1..3}; do

    echo -n "."

    Rscript --vanilla \
      -e 'args <- commandArgs(TRUE)' \
      -e 'invisible(suppressPackageStartupMessages(xdf <- as.data.frame(as.list(system.time(library(args[1], character.only=TRUE), FALSE)))))' \
      -e 'xdf$pkg <- args[1]' \
      -e 'xdf$iter <- args[2]' \
      -e 'xdf$loaded_namespaces <- I(list(loadedNamespaces()))' \
      -e 'saveRDS(xdf, file.path("data", sprintf("%s-%s.rds", args[1], args[2])))' \
      "${pkg}" \
      "${iter}"

  done

  echo ""

done <installed-pkgs.txt
```

I made a `~/projects/pkgbench` directory with a `data` subdir and put ^^ in `~/projects/pkgbench`. With it you:

- get a clean (vanilla) R session each run
- 3 iterations for each (make it higher if you want)
- one RDS file per-iteration
- the number of packages (including names) in the session namespace post-load in the RDS files

When it runs (from a non-RStudio terminal session on your macOS box) you get progress (one dot per iteration):

```
$ ./pkgbench.sh
Benchmarking package [abind]...
Benchmarking package [acepack]...
Benchmarking package [AER]...
Benchmarking package [akima]...
```

You can then do something like (I killed the benchmark after just a few pkgs):

```
library(hrbrthemes) # github/gitlab
library(tidyverse)

map_df(
  list.files("~/projects/pkgbench/data", full.names = TRUE),
  readRDS
) %>% tbl_df() %>% print() -> bench_df
## # A tibble: 141 x 8
##    user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child pkg     iter  loaded_namespaces
##        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <list>           
##  1   0.00500 0.00100  0.00700         0.        0. abind   1     <chr [9]>        
##  2   0.00600 0.00100  0.00700         0.        0. abind   2     <chr [9]>        
##  3   0.00600 0.00100  0.00600         0.        0. abind   3     <chr [9]>        
##  4   0.00500 0.00100  0.00600         0.        0. acepack 1     <chr [9]>        
##  5   0.00600 0.001000 0.00800         0.        0. acepack 2     <chr [9]>        
##  6   0.00500 0.00100  0.00600         0.        0. acepack 3     <chr [9]>        
##  7   1.11    0.0770   1.19            0.        0. AER     1     <chr [36]>       
##  8   1.04    0.0670   1.11            0.        0. AER     2     <chr [36]>       
##  9   1.07    0.0720   1.15            0.        0. AER     3     <chr [36]>       
## 10   0.136   0.0110   0.147           0.        0. akima   1     <chr [12]>       
## # ... with 131 more rows

group_by(bench_df, pkg) %>% 
  summarise(
    med_elapsed = median(elapsed), 
    ns_ct = length(loaded_namespaces[[1]])
  ) -> bench_sum

ggplot(bench_sum, aes("elapsed", med_elapsed)) +
  geom_violin(fill = ft_cols$gray) +
  ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom(color = ft_cols$yellow) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "white", fill="#00000000", outlier.colour = NA) +
  theme_ft_rc(grid="Y")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(bench_sum, aes(ns_ct, med_elapsed)) +
  geom_point(color = ft_cols$yellow) +
  geom_smooth(color = ft_cols$peach) + # shld prbly use something better than loess
  theme_ft_rc(grid = "XY")
```

[image]

If you are going to run it overnight, make sure you disable all "sleepy/idle" time things macOS might do to you (like disable any heavyweight screensavers, prevent it from putting disks to sleep, etc).

Note that I suppressed package startup messages from printing. You may want to `capture.output()` instead or do a comparison with and without that.

`library()` also has all these parameter options:

```
library(
  package, 
  help, 
  pos = 2, 
  lib.loc = NULL,
  character.only = FALSE, 
  logical.return = FALSE,
  warn.conflicts = TRUE, 
  quietly = FALSE,
  verbose = getOption("verbose")
)
```

You may want to tweak those for various benchmarking runs as well.

I also only looked at the median of *"what the package load felt like to the user"* value. Consider examining all of the `system.time` values that are in the data frame.

If your Mac is sufficiently beefy CPU-core-wise and you have a fast solid state disk, you *could* consider using GNU `parallel` with this harness to speed up the timings. I'd definitely use more than 3 iterations per-pkg if you do this and be fairly conservative with the number of concurrent parallel runs.

Comment: I am sorry, my goal was to benchmark package **installation**, not loading!